# Find and copy entire row and insert copied rows below the current row

Tags: excel, vba

I want to run a loop to search the word client in each cell (B column), if any particular cell contains a client then the entire row should be copied. If the cell has three times as client then 3 times row should be pasted then check the next cell of B column.

```
Dim chk As String
Dim Rng As Range
chk = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("clt").Range("A1").Value
LR = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("B1").Select
Set Rng = Range("B1:B" & LR)
For Each cell In Rng
If InStr(LCase(cell.Value), LCase(chk)) <> 0 Then
Cells.Find(what:="Client", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas2, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
        
       
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
   
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy
ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1).Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    End If
Next cell
```

Comment: You have a code and an idea, but not a question. I assume something with the code isn't doing what you want? What isn't working? What is working?

Comment: the code is able to find the word client in B1, then when I try to copy entire row and insert the copied row below the active cell B1 its not working, also I want to run it as a loop. Like when the active cell has 3 times a word client, then it should copy the entire row 3 times and paste it below the active cell in B2, B3, B4 and then move on to the next cell which would be B5

Comment: When you find the word client, you copy the row below that row, and insert in the same place.  Is this intended? You are making a column offset while working with the entire row, this isn't really doing anything. If you insert the row with client, below the row you just found, isn't this going to be the next row with client that the code finds? Thus repeating the process.

Comment: You don't want to loop this per cell, because you find function just finds the next "client" even if far awar from the current cell in the loop.

Comment: When i find the word, i will copy the entire row and insert it below the current row. Yes the code isn't working properly. Let us assume I have only 2 cells with the text inside "Client ABC, Client BCD, Client CDA"  in B1 and "Client EFG, Client GHI , CLient IJK" in cell b2. Now when I run the code it first search word client in cell B1, since have 3 times word client it should copy the entire row 2 times and paste it below b1 like  and b3. Now the original B2 cell which has "Client EFG, Client GHI , CLient IJK" will turn it out as cell B4 and repeat the same procedure

Comment: So the total amount of rows to be copied for each row where "client" is found, is the amount of times the word is found, minus one? So if B1 only had "Client ABC", you wouldn't want a copy at all? If it had "Client ABC, Client BCD" you'd want a single copy, for a total of 2 rows (original B2 now B3)?

Comment: yes you are correct

Comment: Can anyone please help?

Comment: Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

So there's a few things that we need to do.
As always there might be shortcuts, but one approach I found would be this:

First we check how many rows contains the word we're looking for, using the `WorksheetFunction.CountIf`.
Then search the column, to get the first cell.
From here, we use the `FindNext` once for each occurrence, and count how many times the word appears in the cell, using `InStr`

```
Sub searchCopy()
Dim sRng As Range, found As Range, count As Long
Dim i as Long, j as long, k as long
Dim str As String

Set sRng = ActiveSheet.Range("B:B")
str = "client" ' this supposed to be - ThisWorkbook.Sheets("clt").Range("A1").Value - maybe?

count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(sRng, "*" & str & "*")
Set found = sRng.Find(str)
For i = 0 To count - 1
    j = 1
    k = 0
    While InStr(j, found, str, 1) > 0
        j = InStr(j, found, str, 1) + 1
        k = k + 1
    Wend
    If k > 1 Then
        found.EntireRow.Copy
        found.EntireRow.Resize(k - 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    End If
    Set found = sRng.FindNext(found)
Next i
End Sub
```

So we start by looping the search for as many cells as there are hits, minus one. Minus one since we start at the first result already, I only want to loop the `FindNext`.
My "integers" i, j and k, are the loop count, string position and word count respectively.
So we start searching in the first character of the string, and we start at 0 words found.
`Instr` returns the position of the first occurrence of our search, 0 if none.
After we get a match, we add that position to our string position variable, plus one. And add one to the word count.
Then start a new search at this position. This will skip the previous found word, and check if there are any other words.

When the counting is done, we insert the new rows at our current position, so "before" the current row. `FindNext` will not find these rows this time.

Here is a version without the While loop counting, using a replace approach instead:

```
Sub searchCopy()
Dim sRng As Range, found As Range
Dim count As Long, i As Long, j As Long
Dim str As String

Set sRng = ActiveSheet.Range("B:B")
str = "client" 

count = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(sRng, "*" & str & "*")
Set found = sRng.Find(str)
For i = 0 To count - 1
    j = (Len(found) - Len(Replace(UCase(found), UCase(str), ""))) / Len(str)
    If j > 1 Then
        found.EntireRow.Copy
        found.EntireRow.Resize(j - 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    End If
    Set found = sRng.FindNext(found)
Next i
End Sub
```

*Remember, this doesn't check if this has been done before. So if you run it again, you will end up with a bunch of extra rows.*

**New question**

If we want to split the row found into different rows,one per client, we have to make several adjustments.
In the first example we're already keeping track of where the text about the different clients start, so let's save this information.
Now there's a hundred different ways to go about this, but why not use a collection.
We mark down each "start" of a matching string, and then keep going as usual.
After the rows have been inserted – now blank – we can add information to them.
Now there's a bit of math to this, but we need to keep track on which cell to put the information in, and what part of the string we need to copy.
I'm using the `Mid` function to extract the cut string from the original.

**Note** *This will strip any part of the string that comes before the first match.*

```
Sub searchSplit()
Dim sRng As Range, found As Range, count As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim str As String
Dim coll As Collection

Set sRng = ActiveSheet.Range("B:B")
str = "client" 

count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(sRng, "*" & str & "*")
Set found = sRng.Find(str)
For i = 0 To count - 1
    Set coll = New Collection
    j = 1
    While InStr(j, found, str, 1) > 0
        j = InStr(j, found, str, 1) + 1
        coll.Add j - 1
    Wend
    coll.Add Len(found)
    If coll.count > 2 Then
        found.EntireRow.Resize(coll.count - 2).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        For j = 1 To coll.count - 1
            found.Offset(j - (coll.count - 1)).Value = Mid(found, coll(j), coll(j + 1) - coll(j))
        Next j
    End If
    Set found = sRng.FindNext(found)
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you so much for the above code. In addition to the above code can you please make a slight change to the above code like If cell b1 has clients ABC and BCD then we are copying the entire row and pasting it below the current cell. Instead,I just want to copy the details of BCD ignoring details of ABC.

Comment: That could be done. But when you say "details" that tells me nothing. I don't know the formatting of your data. Is it specific cells you want?

Comment: I want to check each cell in column B

Comment: We are checking each cell in column B. For the word Client. Or whatever you put in there. You'd have to be more precise.

Comment: I want to check word client , if a cell B1 has 3 times the word client like Client ABC, client BCD, client CDA then it should copy the cell twice and paste it below in a way such that B2 has information of BCD and B3 should have CDA

Comment: Yes, but where is that information specifically? If I don't know that, how am I supposed to tell excel? Is it in another column, or do you just want to cut out the string in between the words "client"? Is there anything happening in the other column, we are copying the entire row after all.

Comment: The below text is in cell B1, Now I have to copy details of SSS in the below cell B2 and then details of Inc B3 , once it is done I will do text to columns of the entire column

Comment: RUSH - ABC  - CDE - AAAAAA

Client name: HHH
Partner: II
Manager:  JJ
Report Date: Feb 2, 2021
Year End Date: Feb 19, 2020
EQCR (if known):


Client name: SSS
Partner: KK
Manager: LL
Report Date: March 1, 2021
Year End Date:APRIL 1, 2020 
EQCR (if known):

Client: Inc
Partner: Mr. Alph
Manager: AJI
Report Date: March 30, 2021
Year End Date: September 30 2020
EQCR (if known):
Notes:

Comment: That's technically a new question. But I guess we can try to fit it in here...

Comment: Please try to fit it

Comment: Check the answer, I added another section on it.